# filling combobox from xml

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I want to fill my dropdownlist with all the payment methods, i should find the payment methods in an xml file that i have. this should be the xml code for the methods:

```
    Dim xml As String
    xml = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
    xml &= "<gateways ua=""example-php-1.1"">"
    xml &= "<merchant>"
    xml &= " <account>123456</account>"
    xml &= " <site_id>789</site_id>"
    xml &= " <site_secure_code>112233</site_secure_code>"
    xml &= "</merchant>"
    xml &= "<customer>"
    xml &= " <country>NL</country>"
    xml &= " <locale>nl_NL</locale>"
    xml &= "</customer>"
    xml &= " </gateways>"
    Dim apiURl As String

    apiURl = "https://testapi.multisafepay.com/ewx/"


    Dim httpWebRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(apiURl)
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(xml)
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim streamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    streamWriter.Write(xml)
    streamWriter.Close()

    Dim httpWebResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()
    Dim streamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim stringResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    Dim xmlstring As String = stringResult
    Dim xd As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
    xd.LoadXml(xmlstring)
```

the stringResult gives this Value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gateways result="ok">
<gateways>
<gateway>
<id>IDEAL</id>
<description>iDEAL</description>
</gateway>
<gateway>
<id> MASTERCARD</id>
<description>Visa via Multipay</description>
</gateway>
<gateway>
<id> BANKTRANS</id>
<description> Bank Transfer</description>
</gateway>
<gateway>
<id> VISA</id>
<description> Visa CreditCards</description>
</gateway>
</gateways>
</gateways>
```

i need to get the value between the `<id></id>` tags in my ddlMethod how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SelectNodes()` method to get specific nodes from `XmlDocument` passing suitable XPath string as the method parameter. Since `SelectNodes()` returns collection of `XmlNode`, you also need to specify which property of `XmlNode` to be displayed in the dropdown list control. In this case, I assume you want to display the text between `<id>` tags so we use `InnerText` property :

```
Dim xd As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
xd.LoadXml(xmlstring)
'set data source of dropdown to all <id> elements from XML'
ddlMethod.DataSource = xd.SelectNodes("//id")
ddlMethod.DataTextField = "InnerText"
ddlMethod.DataValueField = "InnerText"
ddlMethod.DataBind()
```

Only if available in the .NET framework version you're using, I'd suggest to switch to [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is more modern XML library in .NET compared to the older `XmlDocument`. In various situations `XDocument` is more friendly to use than `XmlDocument`. Example using `XDocument` and LINQ style :

```
Dim xd As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)
'set data soutce of dropdown to *content* of all <id> elements from XML'
ddlMethod.DataSource = xd.Descendants("id").Select(Function(x) x.Value)
ddlMethod.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this and it works for me:

```
 Dim bytTeller As Byte
 For bytTeller = 0 To xd.GetElementsByTagName("gateway").Count - 1
 Dim root As XmlNode = xd.GetElementsByTagName("gateway").Item(bytTeller)
 ddlMethod.Items.Add(root.ChildNodes(0).InnerText)
 Next
```